# Import oracle dump to PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, data-migration

I have a plain text not oracle binary dump. How can I import this to postgres? Are there tools available for this out there? Or is there some other one, anyone did this before?

What I though is to convert one dump (oracle) into another dump (postgres).

Comment: How was this "plain text" dump created? What form is it in?

Comment: Probably it's better to ask http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [ETL tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) like [Talend](http://www.talend.com/index.php) and [Pentaho](http://kettle.pentaho.com/) for conversion between Oracle and PostgreSQL.

From an Oracle dump it's going to be much more difficult. Your best bet is almost certainly to load it into an Oracle instance and then use migration/ETL tools from there. Depending on the dump size, features required, etc, you might be able to use a free Oracle version for this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is feasible in an easy immediate way. Is the plain text in sqlloader format? I think it may be easier for you, if the database size isn't huge, to export DDL and then data in INSERT format.

An alternative would be a migration tool, such as [Talend](http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=6388), but again, it isn't immediate. **The shortest path go through standard SQL**, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

With newer PostgreSQL versions (9.1 or later) you might be able to use a foreign data wrapper to access the Oracle schema from within your PostgreSQL database, e.g.:

http://laurenz.github.io/oracle_fdw/