# How can I convert an Oracle impdp sqlfile to a PostgreSQL script to import data into PostgreSQL?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, insert

I have my hands on an Oracle `.dmp` file and want to import some tables it contains to our PostgreSQL database. The [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11651215/4047679) recommend migration tools on a live Oracle DB, but the table (and therefore, the DB) we're most interested in is [too big for the free Oracle license](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152326/how-can-i-restore-a-10-91g-table-in-oracle-express).
The answer to that question put me down an interesting path: using `impdp` to convert tables in the `.dmp` file to `.sql` scripts. The problem now seems to be making them compatible with PostgreSQL. Each row appears to be `INSERT`d with a format:

```
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt USING 'C',t,p,sp,c,s,
           4,9.15265846187305E-07,4,5740,1,3.49431637447542E+35,4.42973871612322E+35,37,1,5740,4.42973871612322E+35,
           TO_DATE('2016-08-08 22:07:25',df),'434C4F5345442020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020','55504C4F41444544202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020',nv,2,nv;
```

where the `stmt` appears to be duplicating each row by also inserting it into the `"SYS"."IMPDP_STATS" table:

```
stmt varchar(300) = 'INSERT INTO "SYS"."IMPDP_STATS" (type,version,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9,n10,n11,d1,r1,r2,ch1,flags,cl1) VALUES (:1,6,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15,:16,:17,:18,:19,:20,:21,:22,:23)';
```

Using [`SQLines Studio`](http://www.sqlines.com/download) hasn't really helped clean up the PostgreSQL script.

Comment: Short answer: you can't

Comment: You can try to use `sed` or `awk` to massage the SQL file. If the task is too complicated for these tools, write a Perl script. Using prepared statements for the `INSERT` is a good idea.